# What happens if I accept my own answer? Will it improve my accept rate?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

If I answer my own question, and accept my answer, will it improve my accept rate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Accepted answer FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) mentions:

> Which questions do not affect the
>   accept rate?
>
> The following questions are not
>   included in the accept rate
>   calculation:
>
> - Community Wiki questions
> - Closed questions
> - Questions with no answers

So, in short yes it will improve your accept rate.